# 97 Ford Ranger Vehicle Repair

Tags: ford, ranger

When I drive 60 mph, for about 10 min. & slow down to stop at a stop sign, my engine appears to be racing, when I take off from the stop sign & accelerate my engine still appears to be racing. What would cause this, an example: a over drive sensor sticking maybe or something else, please help?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are there any dash lights on?

Comment: Manual or automatic transmission?